# PowerShell Url login and status check

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a simple script that logs in to the pages from the collection and returns confirmation of logging in or no access, at the moment I can successful login but I have no idea how to get the confirmation of It.

Type of error is not my point, only code of ACCESS or DENIED ACCESS

```
[array]$login = "<URL>", "<URL>"

$name = "marek"
$int = Read-Host "write password for user marek: " -AsSecureString
$bstr = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($int)
$pass = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($bstr)

foreach($url in $login) {
    
        $ie = $null
            $ie = New-Object -ComObject 'InternetExplorer.application'
            $ie.Visible = $true

            $ie.Navigate($url)
            While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 1;}

            $namefield = $ie.document.getElementById("id_username")
            $namefield.value = "$name"

            $passfield = $ie.document.getElementById("id_password")
            $passfield.value = "$pass"

            $btn = $ie.document.getElementsByClassName('btn btn-success ml-2')
            $btn[0].click()

            #TODO
            #receive confirmation of loggin or not
```

Comment: If these are internal sites, you can just hit the event log of the web server to get logon info. If these are external sites, of course, that is not an option; so you'd need to know in advance want the landing page is after the logon, and scrape for data to see if you are there.

Comment: This is what I was afraid of, I was thinking about such a solution, but hoped that it could be handled differently ... in this case I would need to create a dictionary for the key: start page, value: end page to somehow automate it.

Comment: No worries, but as an aside, why not use Invok-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod to test web site login vs browser navigation? You can just check for the website status code, without the need to physically navigatge/display pages for logon attempts. Point of note: many site do nto allow automation at all or severly limit it.  What is your goal here. This sounds to me like a recon effort, but , that is an assumption, as I cannot imagine another reason to pass a list of Url wiht creds to test logon. So, color me curious.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment, regarding, why not use `Invoke-*` instead.

MS Docs

[Invoke-WebRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest)
[Invoke-RestMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod)

For example:

*(the below is not generic as each site can/will have a different form field layout/taxonomy for its username, password input.):*

```
$UserCredentials = Get-Credential
$InvokeResponse  = Invoke-WebRequest $Url -SessionVariable MyInvokeSession

$form = $InvokeResponse.Forms
$form.fields['username'] = $UserCredentials.UserName
$form.fields['password'] = $UserCredentials.GetNetworkCredential().Password

$InvokeResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri ($Url + $form.Action) -WebSession $MyInvokeSession -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
```

See this Youtube video to see the details in action/real-time...

> [Logging Into webpage with Invoke-WebRequest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VmHDiXQTs1s)

... and read the details in this article.

> [Web Scraping with PowerShell](https://www.pipehow.tech/invoke-webscrape)

So, as per my comment below, you can use the above to check for success/failure via HTTP status codes...

> https://kinsta.com/blog/http-status-codes

... then, if that shows success, you can use your normal navigation to go there.

Comment: In terms of explaining myself, I have no bad intentions, every morning I have to check 20 url at work and I just wanted to automate it because the login to all of them is the same, and I don't want to have hardcoded passwords in the script. As for the selection of the method, I forgot to add that this is my 4th day with powershell because I have blocked the possibility of pip install and importing modules in python, I could handle the Requests module in a short time, and so I have to learn something new :)

Comment: ***;-}***  `I have no bad intentions, every morning I have to check 20 url at work `  *** ;-}***  `so I have to learn something new `, isn't this always the case for use all. *** ;-}***.  My motto has always been, ABL/ABR (always be learning/always be researching), it's the only way to stay current and ahead of the bell curve, well, mostly. As for your use case. Using the suggestion I made, could validate credential success, before ever trying the site navigation, so, if that comes back fine then branch to opening the site. Again, many sites block or limit automation. Keep that in mind.